# How to automatically add nikud to a text?

Tags: hebrew, vowels-nekudot

I have seen such a site, but cannot find it.

And would it correctly add nikud to this phrase:

שהטוב הוא במאמר שיפעל והרע במאמר שיתפעל כי כל התפעלות רע

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what was so hard, as I googled "nikud" and this was the first result:

http://www.nakdan.com/Nakdan.aspx?lang=eng

Comment: Thank you! When I use google and duck duck go, I do not get that hit (I did try)

Comment: I have it in my favorites, as an alternative to learning how to type niqud and getting fast at it.